# Detect True/False value from a JSON string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following code:

```
string result = "{\n  \"success\": false,\n  \"error-codes\": [\n    \"missing-input-response\"\n  ]\n}";

var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);

var r = results.success;
```

Now I need to know whether r is True or False. Here is what I have:

```
if (r.Equals(false))
{
    //action
}
```

But it appears that the above test is not working. What is the correct way of finding the True or False value in my case?

Comment: Try `bool r = results.success;`

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with a debugger to see what `r` is at runtime?  Verify the type it is deserialized to, and the value.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: John, thanks for improving the question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result).success
```

actually returns an object of type [`JValue`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm), which is not [equal](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue_Equals_1.htm) to `false`.  You need to coerce the return to a boolean first:

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);
bool r = results.success; // Force "success" to be boolean.
if (!r)
{
    // Action.
}
```